# Mdtool generation of makefile

Tags: mono, makefile, monodevelop

I'm currently developing a mono application under the gpl. Therefore I would like to provide a source package with makefile.

I used mdtool to generate simple makefiles:

```
mdtool generate-makefiles AudioCuesheetEditor.sln --simple-makefiles
```

After this, I can successfully run

```
./configure
```

and afterwards

```
make
```

But if I want to run

```
make install
```

it fails with this message:

```
[sven@Sven Downloads]$ make install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make pre-install-local-hook prefix=/usr/local
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make install-satellite-assemblies prefix=/usr/local
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
cp   bin/Release /usr/local/lib/audiocuesheeteditor
cp: Directory „bin/Release“ left out
make[2]: *** [/usr/local/lib/audiocuesheeteditor] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make[1]: *** [install-local] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

If you want to check the build, here's the package: http://sourceforge.net/projects/audiocuesheet/files/0.1.0/Audio%20Cuesheet%20Editor-src.tar.gz/download

Has anyone any idea, why this make install fails?

Answer (score 0):

Makefile integration in MonoDevelop is kind of an abandoned project.

I recommend you to just use MSBuild files (.sln, .csproj, etc), then for building you would just call "xbuild" in your makefile. For installing you may want to create your custom "install" make target, or if you want to experiment doing installation via MSBuild/xbuild, then you may want to look at how are they doing it in the tasque project (source code [here](http://git.gnome.org/browse/tasque/tree/)).

Comment: Well, how can I find xbuild in the internet? What exactly is xbuild? Is it compatible with building guidelines of packages (*.rpm,*.apt,etc.?!).

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Xbuild , also, xbuild is a build tool, not a packaging tool. For packaging I recommend you to use Open Build Service